# How to add a sequence of numbers around each value in a vector

Tags: r, vector

I've got a vector of numbers:

```
vec <- c(50, 75, 100, 125, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 475, 500, 550, 600, 650, 700, 750, 800, 850, 900, 950, 1000)
```

I'd like to add the 10 numbers above and 10 numbers below each value. E.g. for 50 you would add 40 through to 49 and 51 through to 60.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sapply` :

```
c(sapply(vec, `+`, -10:10))
```

If the number overlap you might want to add `unique` to the above output to get only unique values.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `outer` from `base R`

```
c(outer(-10:10, vec, `+`))
```